# Server-Side API Call from JavaScript button?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, server-side, yelp

I have a web app I built that does API calls to Yelp from user input. Right now it's running with Sinatra and pretty much entirely JavaScript. My API calls are run client-side through user input, which results in my userless API tokens/secrets/keys being available. I'm looking to change the app to be a.) more secure and b.) more clean and using the Ruby Yelp API found [here](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby).

My question is this: is it possible to do API calls on the server-side (Ruby) based on user input on the client side without a page refresh? If so, how would the below example be done?

Example: User inputs "Ramen" and "San Francisco" and clicks a button, user input is passed to server-side, server-side API call takes place, client-side grabs JSON response from server-side, client-side displays works with the data

EDIT: I have AJAX in my client-side JavaScript now...is it possible to use AJAX to grab from server-side API calls, i.e. the Yelp Ruby API above?

Comment: You're looking for [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: I guess I should've added: part of my app currently uses AJAX in the client-side JavaScript. I'm wondering if this AJAX can grab from my own server-side API calls

Comment: Yes; in fact that's the most typical use, since grabbing from a different domain requires more work on the source domain's part (or else it can't be done at all).